# HTML canvas transparency never reaches opaque

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, transparency

I've been working on a multi-person drawing application in HTML and JS, but I've run into a strange issue.

To draw, a brush image (loaded from .png) is drawn to the canvas (using `drawImage`) as many times as needed to make a continuous line where the mouse has moved. This all worked fine until I added opacity support. Now I can see that when I turn the opacity right down, even if I scribble back and forth for a long time the image on the canvas never reaches the full colour I'm trying to paint. This results in an odd situation when I can paint a solid, full-opacity black line, then set the opacity really low and attempt to progressively colour over the black line with a transparent red, but the black never ever fades completely to red.

[image: colouring]

I don't understand what's going on here. I've made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seazccv6/) that demonstrates the issue. In the fiddle, no matter how many times the rectangle is drawn over the top of the previous one it never reaches solid black.

Html:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.01;
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 130, 80);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

This makes no sense to me. Does anyone know why this would happen, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Because maths. When you draw 1% opaque red on solid black, the result is 1% red. Do it again and it's 1.99% red. Next one is 2.97% red. Then 3.94% red and so on. 100 applications later you're at 63.4% red. After 500 applications you get 99.33% red. But you'll never reach 100% red because that's how maths works with geometric series... Now factor in that you only have 256 discrete values for how much red there is and you'll fail due to rounding. Specifically, when you get to rgb(207,0,0) then you won't be applying enough red to reach 208, and you get stuck.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What? That doesn't make any sense. Ok, so I'm drawing 255,0,0 with 1% opacity. That means it should simply add 2.55 (or maybe it rounds to 3) red each time. It should reach 255 red in exactly 100 iterations... oh wait, I have no idea how it then moves g and b down to 0... hmm maybe I'm assuming wrongly. Well regardless, every other piece of software I've ever seen will eventually reach a solid colour. Like if I layer two images over the top of each other in HTML alone, they will do what I expect. Why is the canvas different??

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well I'll be damned. I just tried the same thing in PhotoShop and was astounded to see that the "issue" can be replicated exactly! A low-opacity red brush will never fully remove a black line even with hundreds of strokes. Huh. Cool then, it's not an issue. All I have to do now is figure out how to make the temporary stroke layer not look different to the real layer...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol If you convert your comment to an answer (either automatically, assuming you can do that, or copy-paste) I'll accept it since you were correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you draw using a colour with opacity A%, the result will be A% of the way between the colour that's already there, and the (opaque) colour you're drawing with.

In this case, you're drawing with 1% opaque red on solid black. The result will be 1% of the way from black to red. Call this "reddish-black".

Do it again, and the result will be 1% of the way between "reddish-black" and red, which is 1.99% red. Next will be ~2.97% red, then ~3.94% red, and so on. Note that you're not *adding* 1% each time, but advancing 1% of the way to the end from where the previous stroke left you.

Mathematically speaking, you'll keep getting infinitely closer to full-red, but never actually reach it.

But there's an additional factor for graphics: there are only 256 discrete values for how much red you can have: 0 for none, up to 255 for full. At the start your 1% will add 2-3 "units" of red (depending on rounding). This will continue for a while, and gradually fall to just adding 1 "unit" at a time. Finally, you reach 207. At this point there are 48 "units" left to full red, and 1% of that is 0.48 "units". That's not enough, and due to rounding you'll be left with 207 again. This is why you stop seeing any effect after a certain number of strokes.

For a more obvious example, say you're using 50% opaque red to draw. The first stroke will get you 1/2 way there. The second gives another half of that, so 1/2 + 1/4 = 3/4. Then 7/8, then 15/16... Again you'll never actually reach it. Although interestingly in this case the 255-unit thing helps you out, because you'll always be adding at least 0.5 "units" which will round up to +1 until you reach full red.